# Guarantee best audio with best-merge?

Tags: yt-dlp

I'm trying to dl the highest quality audio (and this is the most important thing), but also specific video formats.  My default setting would probably be "best-video", but it might be something like 480p....  Anyway, the issue I've been having is that **best video overrides best audio** with the command I am currently using:

`yt-dlp -f bestvideo*+bestaudio`

What I want to accomplish is getting the best video quality and overwriting its audio file with the best audio file.

Comment: You'd probably have to do an individual download of the best audio and then use something like `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -map 0:v? -map 1:a? -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4` to merge them. (Only a comment because the ffmpeg command is off the top of my head and I don't have a way to test it at the moment.

Comment: … or just use JDownloader instead...